# Application Insights Configuration

Tags: azure, app-insight

I'm trying to follow the steps from this blog to push the logs for the sitecore application to App Insights however it doesn't seem to push the logs

https://jan-v.nl/post/using-application-insights-in-your-log4net-application
 to APP insights.

How to do the client side telemetry implementation with sitecore?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried [this](https://github.com/SC-MNAS/Sitecore-Azure/wiki/Configuring-Application-Insights-for-Sitecore-8.2)? If at some point, you want to revert back to having configs under "App_Data", all you have to do is remove the config file within zzz folder and restart app pool. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 4):

This is because Sitecore includes it's own (old) version of log4net in the `Sitecore.Logging` assembly.

Bas Lijten has written [a blog post about this](http://blog.baslijten.com/improving-the-sitecore-logging-and-diagnostics-experience-part-1-expose-more-information-using-a-new-logger/) and how to extend the Sitecore logging.

Here's part of his summary at the end:

> The default Sitecore implementation of log4net is not optimal, the implementation is outdated and doesn’t support 3rd party add-ons. It’s not hard to improve the current implementation and building a custom logger façade to use the Sitecore log4net implementation and to be able to write into the standard sitecore logs, is quite easy and opens up possibilities. One of these possibilities is append the information to application insights and take the insights to the next level, as every logged item, your custom logs, as well as the Sitecore logs, would can be correlated and be traced

Basically you have to create your own appender referencing Sitecore's version of log4net.

Below is an appender I've been using, which is a cleaned/slightly modified version of [Bas Lijten's version](https://github.com/BasLijten/SitecoreDiagnostics/blob/master/BasLijten.Sitecore.Diagnostics.ApplicationInsights/ApplicationInsightsAppender.cs). Just make sure you are referencing `Sitecore.Logging`.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;
using log4net.Appender;
using log4net.spi;
using Microsoft.ApplicationInsights;
using Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Channel;
using Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.DataContracts;
using Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensibility.Implementation;

namespace Sandbox.ApplicationInsights
{
    public sealed class ApplicationInsightsAppender : AppenderSkeleton
    {
        private TelemetryClient TelemetryClient { get; set; }

        /// <summary> 
        /// The <see cref="T:Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Log4NetAppender.ApplicationInsightsAppender" /> requires a layout. 
        /// This Appender converts the LoggingEvent it receives into a text string and requires the layout format string to do so. 
        /// </summary> 
        protected override bool RequiresLayout => true;

        /// <summary> 
        /// Initializes the Appender and perform instrumentationKey validation. 
        /// </summary> 
        public override void ActivateOptions()
        {
            base.ActivateOptions();

            TelemetryClient = new TelemetryClient
            {
                Context =
                {
                    InstrumentationKey = "<YOUR INSTRUMENTATION KEY>"
                }
            };

            TelemetryClient.Context.GetInternalContext().SdkVersion = "Log4Net: " + GetAssemblyVersion();
        }

        /// <summary> 
        /// Append LoggingEvent Application Insights logging framework. 
        /// </summary> 
        /// <param name="loggingEvent">Events to be logged.</param> 
        protected override void Append(LoggingEvent loggingEvent)
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(loggingEvent.GetExceptionStrRep()))
            {
                SendException(loggingEvent);
                return;
            }
            SendTrace(loggingEvent);
        }

        private static string GetAssemblyVersion()
        {
            return
                typeof (ApplicationInsightsAppender).Assembly.GetCustomAttributes(false)
                    .OfType<AssemblyFileVersionAttribute>()
                    .First()
                    .Version;
        }

        private static void AddLoggingEventProperty(string key, string value, IDictionary<string, string> metaData)
        {
            if (value != null)
            {
                metaData.Add(key, value);
            }
        }

        private void SendException(LoggingEvent loggingEvent)
        {
            try
            {
                var exception = GetException(loggingEvent);
                var exceptionTelemetry = new ExceptionTelemetry(exception)
                {
                    SeverityLevel = GetSeverityLevel(loggingEvent.Level)
                };
                BuildCustomProperties(loggingEvent, exceptionTelemetry);
                TelemetryClient.Track(exceptionTelemetry);
            }
            catch (ArgumentNullException ex)
            {
                throw new LogException(ex.Message, ex);
            }
        }

        private static Exception GetException(LoggingEvent loggingEvent)
        {
            var exception = GetInstanceField(typeof(LoggingEvent), loggingEvent, "m_thrownException");
            return exception as Exception;
        }

        private static object GetInstanceField(Type type, object instance, string fieldName)
        {
            var field = type.GetField(fieldName, BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Static);
            return field?.GetValue(instance);
        }

        private void SendTrace(LoggingEvent loggingEvent)
        {
            try
            {
                var message = (loggingEvent.RenderedMessage != null) ? RenderLoggingEvent(loggingEvent) : "Log4Net Trace";
                var traceTelemetry = new TraceTelemetry(message)
                {
                    SeverityLevel = GetSeverityLevel(loggingEvent.Level)
                };
                BuildCustomProperties(loggingEvent, traceTelemetry);
                TelemetryClient.Track(traceTelemetry);
            }
            catch (ArgumentNullException ex)
            {
                throw new LogException(ex.Message, ex);
            }
        }

        private static void BuildCustomProperties(LoggingEvent loggingEvent, ITelemetry trace)
        {
            trace.Timestamp = loggingEvent.TimeStamp;
            trace.Context.User.Id = loggingEvent.UserName;

            var telemetry = trace as ExceptionTelemetry;
            var properties = telemetry != null 
                ? telemetry.Properties 
                : ((TraceTelemetry) trace).Properties;

            AddLoggingEventProperty("LoggerName", loggingEvent.LoggerName, properties);
            AddLoggingEventProperty("ThreadName", loggingEvent.ThreadName, properties);

            var locationInformation = loggingEvent.LocationInformation;
            if (locationInformation != null)
            {
                AddLoggingEventProperty("ClassName", locationInformation.ClassName, properties);
                AddLoggingEventProperty("FileName", locationInformation.FileName, properties);
                AddLoggingEventProperty("MethodName", locationInformation.MethodName, properties);
                AddLoggingEventProperty("LineNumber", locationInformation.LineNumber, properties);
            }

            AddLoggingEventProperty("Domain", loggingEvent.Domain, properties);
            AddLoggingEventProperty("Identity", loggingEvent.Identity, properties);

            var eventProperties = loggingEvent.Properties;
            if (eventProperties == null)
                return;

            var keys = eventProperties.GetKeys();
            foreach (var text in keys)
            {
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(text) || text.StartsWith("log4net", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                    continue;

                var obj = eventProperties[text];
                if (obj != null)
                {
                    AddLoggingEventProperty(text, obj.ToString(), properties);
                }
            }
        }

        private static SeverityLevel? GetSeverityLevel(Level logginEventLevel)
        {
            if (logginEventLevel == null)
                return null;

            if (logginEventLevel < Level.INFO)
                return SeverityLevel.Verbose;

            if (logginEventLevel < Level.WARN)
                return SeverityLevel.Information;

            if (logginEventLevel < Level.ERROR)
                return SeverityLevel.Warning;

            if (logginEventLevel < Level.SEVERE)
                return SeverityLevel.Error;

            return SeverityLevel.Critical;
        }
    }
}
```